# PIC16F77 ADC not producing 0v result with 0v input

Tags: pic, adc

I've set up a PIC16F77 to repeatedly sample an analogue DC signal. The problem is when I apply a 0v signal, the ADC does not read as `0x00`. It's an 8-bit ADC and at 0v reads about `0x05` - `0x06`. (I'm using the Vref pin for scaling, and have set it to 2.55V).

What I have done to try to fix the issue:

- A well regulated 5v power supply
- Smoothing capacitors on the Vref pin
- Smoothing capacitors on the power supply
- Tied all other analogue inputs to ground
- Increased the acquisition delay to about 40us (recommended is 16us)
- The signal to the analogue inputs is in the order of a few ohms - the recommended is less than 10k

The datasheet says +/- 1LSB should be possible, and I'm mystified. Can I expect better from this PIC? And how can it be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get that reading with the ADC input grounded?

Comment: Are you breadboarding this? If so, could you share a detailed photo of your connection?

Comment: Can you try taking readings with the ADC input connected directly to analog ground with a short wire? I know you say you have 0V signal but that's not quite the same.

Comment: Yes that is with the analogue input going to ground with a short wire on a breadboard ... I will tidy it up and take a photo

Comment: Do you have a schematic? My guess would be that your ADC pin is floating, i.e you have to choose a proper pull down resistor if you need it to read 0x00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared, and I'm not entirely sure why, as I have not been able to replicate the problem I had, once it disappeared! But I made the following changes:

1. Replaced the uC. Perhaps the other one was *slightly* damaged
2. Changed configuration of ADC/Digital ports as below:

To quote the datasheet on "**Configuring analog port pins**" section:

> Analog levels on any pin that is defined as a digital input, but not
>   as an analog input, may cause the digital input buffer to consume
>   current that is out of the device's specifications.

Both before, and after the problem, I had set bits `PCFG2:PCFG00` to `011` (`ADCON1` register) which sets:

- RA0, RA1, RA2, RA5 pins to analogue inputs
- RA3 as the Vref pin
- RE0, RE1, RE2 as digital IO.

I had tied RA0, RA1, RA2 and RA5 to ground to test if they were outputting `0x00`.  *Before the changes* **were not** `0x00`, but *after the changes*, **were** `0x00`.

**The problem/solution:**

I had left RE0, RE1, and RE2 as digital inputs rather than outputs. I left them floating. This may have caused problems as described in the quoted paragraph (above), possibly damaging the chip. In other words, I had initially set `TRISE` register to `00000111`.

I believe setting `TRISE` to `00000000` instead may be what fixed the issue. Perhaps a second solution would have been to simply tie RE0, RE1 and RE2 to ground or +5v.

Answer (score 1):

I was researching this same problem I was having with a PIC ADC and  came across this old thread. It led me to try something different to what is discussed here and voila it worked. So I guess an update to this old thread is in order.

I tried changing the TRIS register as discussed here but with mixed results on a PIC12F1840 - it solves the minimum reading but when connecting the pin to VDD the reading is lower than the expected 0x3FF. I had WPU enabled on the pin so I changed WPU to OFF and voila, problem solved. Both min and max readings are correct. eg `WPUAbits.WPUA0 = 0`.

Kinda makes sense if you think about it but nowhere that I could find is it mentioned to beware of in the datasheet when configuring an ADC input.

Readings across the range are also affected - except at input = VDD which gives the correct ADC result of 0x3FF. Clearly current flowing through the 20k-100k WPU device combined with the high input impedance of the ADC port upsets the ADC reading.

Default state for WPUs are disabled through WPUEN bit so I guess you can call it a misconfiguration of the ADC pin on my part but with no warnings in the datasheet.

This may well also be true for other devices with WPU such as the OP's 16F77 which has WPU on PortB. Probably too long ago to be relevant to him now tho, hopefully other folk will find this helpful.